# Airprint > High Resolution > Duplex possible

Tags: swift, ios8, duplex, airprint

Coming from Android I am new to iOS development and need advice :-)

In a current project I need to print variable content (product, map and cam-picture) in high resolution in duplex mode via airprint. The structure and layout (of the pages) is delivered via JSON-File.

1. Is there a decent way to generate a "layout-framework" to separate the displayed views/content on screen and the content to be printed as I do not need the high resolution for display purposes? Any projects dealing with similar approaches to start from someone can advice? Any kind of "JSON to layout/structure parser"?
2. Is it in general possible to print duplex high-resolution content maybe even borderless if the printer supports this mode? Could not find an answer here: 
   *...developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html*
3. What is the smartest way to render the print content? Rendering a second high resolution "print-view" offscreen or generate a pdf and print that? This I found [this](http://cadabracorp.com/blog/2012/09/26/creating-printing-and-emailing-high-resolution-pdfs-in-ios/).
4. How would I airprint with swift given the requirements can be addressed? A good starter I found [here](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/airprint-tutorial-ios8-swift).

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I find [WWDC session videos about printing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) to be excellent primers and provide great answers to what's there. It covers the content in [the Printing page you linked](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html) but in more task-oriented detail. Between the tools to use views, draw with Core Graphics/Quartz (which can work with PDFs) and providing the content as HTML to be printed by WebKit, you should be able to find a good approach.

Most printer features you could ask for are there. Beyond B&W/color inkjet/laser printers, iOS printing supports both large-format printers as well as even line printers. Both duplex printing and borderless printing are definitely supported.

As for 4: Just write the same code you would write in Objective-C, but do it in Swift. Any library, including what Apple provides, that helps you print from Objective-C can be used from Swift.

Comment: Thanks Jesper for the answer. Those videos (2012:234, 2013:711, 2014:718) I watched and got to know that UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto in high quality does not allow for duplex (718_adopting_airprint:42) hence I wonder if there is a way to circumvent this restriction. Otherwise I think I´ll have to take the pdf approach.

Comment: I think "normal quality" is a relative measure - most photo printers do not support duplex for the reason that photos and photo paper are not naturally duplex, but on printers geared towards high-resolution output where you are meant to be able to print duplex, normal quality will be high quality.